# How to pause UI updates in android?

Tags: android, asynchronous

I have a Android application where its Main activity constantly download and parse a XML from the internet using `AsyncTask` and update the value to UI using `onPostExecute();`

However,

there is a EditText which can edit value and update to XML using a button as well.

but I couldn't input any value on the EditText as the it is updated by `onPostExecute();` every 3 second.

(by the time i finish input my value, it is wash out by the updated value from XML)

I have implement `onClickListener();` and tried `onPause();` but did not work.

How should I pause the UI update/application?

EDIT #1

```
Protected Void onCreate(...){
    ......
    listener();
    runnablecode.run();
}

public void run(){
    AsyncDownloader downloadxml = new AsyncDownloader();
    downloadxml.execute();
    handler.postDelay(runnablCode,poll_interval);
}
private void listener();{
    EditText atten = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.attenEditText);
    atten.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){
        //I want to pause UI updating the EditText here
        return false;
       }
    });
}
```

Comment: post relevant code snippet please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pause - resume is not possible with async task. you will have to handle it with some hacks.

instead try cancel and start again after you input/process the edit text.

see [Pause and Resume AsyncTasks? (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474584/pause-and-resume-asynctasks-android)

Answer (score 0):

you can check if the EditText is in focus before update by async task。

Comment: AsyncTask is initialize onCreate, and looping every 3 second