# Android activity LifeCycle, whitch method to run while loop when app is runnig?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-studio

I have created an app that is searhcing for bigger and bigger primes and saves them in a textfile. Right know im letting the user to click a button to make the app search for bigger primes and save the to file.

Istead of clicking i want the app to run a while loop in the background and do the searching and saving by it self without any user interaction.

Is the onStart(); a good method to put the while loop in so it runs in the background while the app is running?
Also should i use te Runnable interface to dynamically show the user wich prime is found and saved to the file?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: An operation like the one you describe is best done in a background thread. If you want the option of displaying the data from the function call, look into using an AsyncTask.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Service if your while loop will do a lot of work or consider using AsyncTask (a few seconds at the most.).

A Service is an application component representing either an application's desire to perform a longer-running operation while not interacting with the user or to supply functionality for other applications to use ([here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html))

AsyncTask enables proper and easy use of the UI thread.[here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

As mentioned @EpicPandaForce, if you're doing a CPU intensive(mp3 for eg.) consider using an `IntentService` because it is executed on another thread.

Comment: I personally recommend an `IntentService` because it is executed on another thread.

Comment: I know :D I just figured I'd mention that extending `Service` itself would be a bad choice because it still executes on the UI Thread

Comment: is it possible to pause AsyncTask with onPause() and then start the AsyncTask in the onResume() ?

i manage to stop the Task with:
`protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Log.d("Method:","OnPause();");
        new MyClass().cancel(true);

    }`
 

But this dosent work:

` protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        Log.d("Method:","onResume();");
        new MyClass().execute();
    }`

Comment: Have a look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474584/pause-and-resume-asynctasks-android